# Prove the curve is a part of circle

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, curvature

Given a curve $y$ having constant curvature with $y=f(x)$ with $f''(x) > 0 $. I have to prove that this curve is a part of a circle.

My Try

Assume curvature of the curve as $c$. Then, I can write $$c = \frac{f''(x)}{(1+f'(x)^2)^{\frac 32}}$$
After this, I am unable to solve the non-linear differential equation.

Is my approach wrong?
Thanks in advance !

Comment: Since you do not have $f$ itself in the equation, you can solve for $g=f'$.
$$
g'=c(1+g^2)^{3/2}
$$
which is separable, and then integrate once more to get $f$.

Comment: I tried it... this didn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you separate the variables in the equation for $g=f'$ you obtain
$$
\frac{dg}{(1+g^2)^{3/2}}=cdx
$$
With the substitution $g=\tan\theta$ the integral on the left is just $\sin\theta+const.$ so
$$
\sin\theta=cx+D
$$
If we choose as our initial direction $\theta=0$ (the curve starts horizontally at $x=0$) you get $D=0$. Since $\sin\theta=\tan\theta/\sqrt{1+\tan^2\theta}=g/\sqrt{1+g^2}$ we have
$$
\frac{g}{\sqrt{1+g^2}}=cx.
$$
Solving for $g$:
$$
g(x)=\frac{cx}{\sqrt{1-c^2x^2}},
$$
for $|x|\in[0,1/c)$. Integrating once again
$$
f(x)=-\frac{\sqrt{1-c^2x^2}}{c}+E
$$
Choosing the initial point of the curve at the origin, we find $E=\frac 1{c}$. Finally,
$$
f(x)=\frac 1{c}-\frac{\sqrt{1-c^2x^2}}{c}
$$
which is the lower half of the circle centered at $(0,1/c)$ with radius $1/c$, as expected (the radius is the reciprocal of the curvature).